# XmlSerializer - Add as Empty Element for Null property in Object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

When serializing a `object` to `XML`, When object property values are null `Serializer` is not adding that element. How to add that element in XML with empty value?

eg:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName ="Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EmployeeId", IsNullable = false)]
    public int EmployeeId {get;set;}

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EmployeeName", IsNullable = false)]
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
}
```

Serializer Class

```
public static class GenericXmlSerializer
{
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new SystemXml.XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Parsing

```
var emp = new Employee();
emp.SerializeObject();
```

Actual Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Entity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Entity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
<Employee>
   <EmployeeId></EmployeeId>
   <EmployeeName></EmployeeName>
</Employee>
```

Any Ideas?

**Edited after a comment:**

When changing `IsNullable=true`, the output is something like below which is not as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <EmployeeId xsi:nil="true" />
</Employee>
```

Comment: [XmlElement(ElementName = "EmployeeId", IsNullable = true)] can you try like this.please set  IsNullable = true and try.

Comment: @Joseph, Please see my edits

Comment: please look into this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Joseph, Thanks! `DefaultValue` may help me, but it is not working as intended, Also I need  to mark every property with `DefaultValue` and need to have `Reset`  method which is complex when there is lot of properties. Any best and efficient way to achieve it ?